# Print largest & second largest number from three variables entered by the user by conditional statement

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

Hey I recently started to learn python. Below is the program to find the largest number, I want to know how do I print the second largest number. Thanks in advance.

```
x=int(input("Enter the 1st number: \n"))
y=int(input("Enter the 2nd number: \n"))
z=int(input("Enter the 3rd number: \n"))

if x>y:
    f1=x
else:
    f1=y

if y>z:
    f2=y
else:
    f2=z
    
if f1>f2:
    print(str(f1)+" is greatest")
else:
    print(str(f2)+" is greatest")
```

Comment: Can you put all in a list then sort the list ?

Comment: I don't want to use list... I want to do it with conditional statements only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get the second largest number by adding the input to a list and sorting it.

Try this:

```
xyz = [x,y,z]
sorted_xyz = sorted(xyz)
largest = sorted_xyz[-1]
second_largest = sorted_xyz[-2]
```

Since you want this to work with conditional statements. You can try:

```
# check if x is the largest
if ( x >= y and x >= z ):
    print(str(x) + " is the greatest")
    # check if y is greater than z, if so then it is the second largest number.
    if ( y >= z ):
        print(str(y) + " is second greatest")
    else:
        print(str(z) + " is second greatest")

# check if y is the largest
if ( y >= x and y >= z ):
    print(str(y) + " is the greatest")
    # check if x is greater than z, if so then it is the second largest number.
    if ( x >= z ):
        print(str(x) + " is second greatest")
    else:
        print(str(z) + " is second greatest")

# check if z is the largest
if ( z >= x and z >= y ):
    print(str(z) + " is the greatest")
    # check if x is greater than y, if so then it is the second largest number.
    if ( x >= y ):
        print(str(x) + " is second greatest")
    else:
        print(str(y) + " is second greatest")
```

Comment: Is there any other way by conditional statements... or by bool operators?

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: Thank you so so much... this is what I needed.

Comment: Great, you can mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

use `min` and `max`, which are python's builtins

```py
x = 12
y = 5
z = 3
second_max = min(x, max(y, z))
print(second_max)
```

out

```
5
```

no matter the values, you will always get the second max.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
x=int(input("Enter the 1st number: \n"))
y=int(input("Enter the 2nd number: \n"))
z=int(input("Enter the 3rd number: \n"))

numbers_in_ascending_order = sorted([x,y,z])

numbers_in_descending_order = numbers_in_ascending_order.reverse()

second_largest = numbers_in_descending_order[1]

print("second largest:"+second_largest.__str__())
```

or you can try this:

```
x=int(input("Enter the 1st number: \n"))
y=int(input("Enter the 2nd number: \n"))
z=int(input("Enter the 3rd number: \n"))
lst = [x,y,z]
lst.sort(reverse=True)
second_greatest = lst[1]
print("second greatest:"+second_greatest.__str__())
```

Out:

```
>>> python3 test.py
Enter the 1st number:
3
Enter the 2nd number:
5
Enter the 3rd number:
12
second greatest:5
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using booleans, use sorted:

```
x=int(input("Enter the 1st number: \n"))
y=int(input("Enter the 2nd number: \n"))
z=int(input("Enter the 3rd number: \n"))
print(f'Second largest number is {sorted([x,y,z])[-2]}')
```

This works for as many inputs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same method but a little bit complicated. You can try this code:

```
x = int(input("Enter the 1st number: \n"))
y = int(input("Enter the 2nd number: \n"))
z = int(input("Enter the 3rd number: \n"))


if x < y and x > z or x < z and x > y:
    print("this is second largest number", str(x))


if y < x and y > z or y < z and y > x:
    print("this is second largest number", str(y))


if z < x and z > y or z < y and z > y:
    print("this is second largest number", str(z))
```

I personally wouldn't prefer this because it is too long, it works only with these 3 variabels, and wouldn't work for long numbers. But for a beginner it should be enough.

Comment: Thanks... its better to understand as a beginner.

Comment: It won't print anything for 3 equal values.

Comment: and that is correct because in this case there is no largest and second largest number cause all ar equal

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on conditionals:

```
if x <= y <= z or z <= y <= x:
    print(y)
elif y <= x <= z or z <= x <= y:
    print(x)
else:
    print(z)
```

The code is based on 6 possible ordering of 3 values (xyz, xzy, ...).

However, it works only for exactly 3 values and is not scalable.